# how get all tables where name of table between a date

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-micro-integrator

I have an api that allows get all tables that are between two specific dates ,at first i tried to put query parameters comme ci-dessous
[image]
I used enrich mediator to display table to the do substring
this my code

```
        <inSequence>
            <script language="js"><![CDATA[var table = mc.getProperty('query.param.table');
table =table.toString();
mc.setProperty('table',table);]]></script>
            <property expression="get-property('table')" name="uri.var.table" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
            <call>
                <endpoint>
                    <http method="get" uri-template="http://ITMTNF3RRJSJ:8290/services/studenttest/readtable?table={uri.var.table}">
                        <suspendOnFailure>
                            <initialDuration>-1</initialDuration>
                            <progressionFactor>-1</progressionFactor>
                            <maximumDuration>0</maximumDuration>
                        </suspendOnFailure>
                        <markForSuspension>
                            <retriesBeforeSuspension>0</retriesBeforeSuspension>
                        </markForSuspension>
                    </http>
                </endpoint>
            </call>
            <enrich>
                <source clone="true" type="inline">
                    {"nomtable":""
                    }
                </source>
                <target action="child" xpath="json-eval($.tables)"/>
            </enrich>
            <enrich>
                <source clone="true" property="uri.var.table" type="property"/>
                <target xpath="json-eval($.tables.nomtable)"/>
            </enrich>
               <iterate expression="//tables">
                <target>
                    <sequence>
            <property expression="json-eval($.tables.nomtable)" name="nomtable" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
            <log level="custom">
                <property expression="get-property('nomtable')" name="m"/>
            </log>
                        <script language="js"><![CDATA[var str = mc.getProperty('nomtable');
var annee= str.substr(1, 4);
annee==annee.toString();
var mois=str.substr(5, 2);
var jour=str.substr(7, 2);
mc.setProperty('annee',annee);
mc.setProperty('mois',mois);
mc.setProperty('jour',jour);]]></script>
                        <log level="custom">
                            <property expression="get-property('annee')" name="annee" />
                        </log>
                        <log level="custom">
                            <property expression="get-property('mois')" name="mois" />
                        </log>
                        <log level="custom">
                            <property expression="get-property('jour')" name="jour" />
                        </log>
                    </sequence>
                </target>
            </iterate>
            <property name="messageType" scope="axis2" type="STRING" value="application/json"/>
            <property name="ContentType" scope="axis2" type="STRING" value="application/json"/>
            <respond/>
```

but i have the  result

`` INFO {LogMediator} - m = `20221018`,`20221211`  INFO {LogMediator} - {api:student} annee = 2022 mois = 10 jour = 18 ``

the problem i have two name of table as a date `20221018`and `20221211`i want extract annee mois and jour of the two table  but i can't browse both tables .

Comment: My objective the user put as parameter two date (table name) it is displayed all the tables which are between them